# LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting error

```
#7890 - Can't find file 'C:UsersAdminDesktopBL postcodes.csv.zip'.
```

here is the script

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\BL postcodes.csv.zip' 
IGNORE INTO TABLE uk_pc 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
(Postcode, Latitude, Longitude, Easting, Northing, GridRef, County, District, Ward, DistrictCode, WardCode, Country, CountyCode)
```

i have tried to change folders and change permission also but same error ... (working on localhost server)

Comment: `'C:UsersAdminDesktopBL postcodes.csv.zip'` path has to be wrong cuz it doesn't have traling slashes.
try: `INFILE 'C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\BL postcodes.csv.zip' `

Comment: @Disa Thx it worked but getting another error now data is my database get in wrong format some thing like this ** §@¼eSìï ®·ÔÙÇT    Š!žfÈ3tx}ºz¹àì6¿uÏÍ¿ÑæË...** where am i getting wrong now :(

Comment: I am not sure if you could use .zip. Try unpacking it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need a regular plain-text file and compression is not supported.

Comment: @Disa Yaa great it worked  ;) thx ... can u make it as ans so i can accept it and close my question .:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`'C:UsersAdminDesktopBL postcodes.csv.zip'` path has to be wrong because it doesn't have traling slashes. try: INFILE `'C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\BL postcodes.csv.zip'`

And try with unpacked file.

Answer (score -1):

use local infile like below:

load data local infile 'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\' into table user