# Insert Large (4 GB) CSV into Mysql Database (web server)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, csv

I have been researching this topic for a while now with no success.  Here's the problem:
I have a 4.5GB csv file I need to insert into my mysql database.  The file is too large to import through phpmyadmin (55 MiB max) and is too large to upload to my web server (1000 MB max disk space).  At this point I'm not sure it is even possible to accomplish what I need to do.  I know how to use LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE, but I cant execute the command without the csv file being already on my web server.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

A side note if it is at all helpful:  I downloaded the csv file from ftp://alt.ncsbe.gov/data.  This site is where I get my information weekly.  I'm not sure if it's possible to download the information I need from said site and insert it into my database without downloading it to my physical machine.  Just a random thought, but I'm more focused on the first problem.

Comment: Where is your MySQL instance running?  Will that instance allow a database of that size?  Not if it's running on the web server, or an identically configured machine.

Comment: Assuming that the MySQL instance *does* permit a database of that size, does it permit remote connections or are you only able to connect from the webserver?  If you can connect remotely, you might be able to use a MySQL client (whether the official command-line tool, the official Workbench GUI, or some third party application) with `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` (server configuration permitting); otherwise you'd probably have to divide the CSV into 1GiB chunks (or perhaps your host will provide you with some exceptional access, e.g. email to them the link to the CSV for them to manually import).

Comment: How big will the MySQL database be once you have loaded this file? Try it locally, and if it is larger than 1G then I assume you'll need to upgrade your hosting account. Bear in mind that setting up a machine that can do this - if you are willing to manage a VPS on your own - can cost a few GBP/USD per month - so there's little value in struggling with an unsuitable account.

Comment: I guess I was right and it just isn't possible on such a small web server.  Thanks for the confirmation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm actually working with the same data source.

This seems to work well for me: LOAD DATA INFILE 'ncvoter92.txt' INTO TABLE nc.ncvoter92 COLUMNS TERMINATED BY '\t' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES;

If you are looking for a GUI option I had much better success using phpMyAdmin's import functionality:

- Format = CSV (NOT CSV using LOAD DATA)
- Columns separated with = \t
- Columns enclosed with = "
- Columns escaped with = "
- Lines terminated with = auto
- CHECK = The first line of the file contains the table column names (if this is unchecked, the first line will become part of the data)

BTW... I noticed much many of the flat files on the FTP have consistency issues at least on a Linux server. You may need to clean up the data a bit to help avoid errors.

Hope this helps! Feel free to reach out if you have specific questions about the data source.

Comment: I used something similar: LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/user/public_html/path/to/file/ncvoter_Statewide.txt' INTO TABLE week1 COLUMNS TERMINATED BY '\t' ENCLOSED by '"' (@ignore,county,voternum,@ignore,status,@ignore,...,); How do you use the import function with 4.5 Gig text files? For me, 52 MB is the max file size.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the mysql server accepts remote connections the following command will work (it works for me with amazon AWS (Amazon Relational Database Service). It also assumes that it has the space for it as mysql will write it to disk. It really depends on your set-up as it could use a different partition with more space.

You need the run the command on your own machine, --local specifies that the file is local.

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlimport.html for more details.

```
mysqlimport --fields-terminated-by=,\
            --local\
            --host=example.com \
            -u username\
            -p /path/to/csv-file
```

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to use LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE on .zip files?  This would allow me to upload the txt file to my web server and use the LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE command without running out of disk space.

Comment: I've never tried it but it seems possible: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13979689/load-data-local-infile-php-mysql) You could also split the in 5 files less than 1GB each and import them separately *as long as you have enough space for the database itself*

Comment: From the link you posted: "I'm pretty sure you need a regular plain-text file and compression is not supported."